# Selenium unable to create new session

Tags: selenium

This is coming about because I have a failing Behat test on a search field - the field is added via javascript so I assumed something was wrong with (with my setup of) Selenium.

I found that if I visit http://localhost:4444/wd/hub and click "Create Session", select *any* of the browsers (android, iphone, firefox, chrome, internet explorer, opera) I get the error message: `Unable to create new session`.

I'm not sure if the two are related (failing `@javacript` tests and unable to create a session).

I am starting Selenium with `java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar -port 4444` on osX Sierra 10.12.5.

My current configuration in behat.yml is

```
javascript_session: selenium2
  goutte: ~
  selenium2:
    wd_host: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
```

Although I wouldn't expect that to affect the ability to create a session from `/wd/hub`.

Answer (score 7):

The issue was that I didn't have a driver.  I [downloaded Gecko Driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), moved the executable to `/usr/local/bin` and all is well.